# How to set data members of derived product class in factory design pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory-pattern

How to set data members of derived product class in factory design pattern?

```
class Factory
{
  public:
     product* Create(int type)
     {
        switch (type)
        {
           case 1:
             return new product1;
           break;
           case 2:
             return new product2;
           break;
        }
     }
};

class product
{
  int a;
  public :
  product(); 
  product(int a); 
  void seta (int a);
};

class product1:public product
{
  int b;
public:
  product1();
  product1(int a,int b):product(a), b(b) {}
  void setb (int b);
};

class product2:public product
{
  int c;
public:
  product2();
  product2(int a, int c):product(a), c(c) {}
  void setc (int c);
};


\\ client code 

void main()
{
  Factory f;
  product* p = f.create(1); // product1 created
  p->seta(2);
  // now how to set value b of product1
}
```

Note: if I down cast the p to p1 then there will be no point of using factory.
Hence don't know how to use it.

EDIT : 
set method added for product, product1, product2.
How to set value for b in main if product1 created using factory?

Comment: This won't compile - `product1` and `product2` don't have zero-parameter constructors. Just give them constructors that take as many parameters as they have members to initialize, and call those constructors from `Factory::Create`. It's not quite clear from your description, thought, where `Factory` is supposed to take actual values for `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: Please see my edit section.  Lets ssay product1 need 1 argument to construct it and product2 need 2 then How many argument should I pass to Factory::Create apart from type Factory::Create(type, a) or Factory::Create(type,a,b);

Comment: This design doesn't make much sense. Presumably, the point of having a `Factory` is to hide implementation details from clients behind a uniform interface. But if the client must know which parameters of which types each kind of product requires in order to call `Factory::Create`, this would defeat the whole point - with this amount of knowledge, the client might as well just create `product1` and `product2` directly.

Answer (score 0):

`product` could have some (pure) virtual methods. The effect of calling such methods depends on the dynamic type of the object, no downcast is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally `b` would be set by the `Factory` during `create`. Is there any reason why that is not possible?

Failing that, you will probably have to set `b` via a `virtual` method on `Product`. Preferably via a `virtual` method that makes sense in the context of all `Product`s.

Where does the value of `b` come from?  For example,  say the value comes from a file, it might make sense to have a virtual method `Product::setThingsFromFile(string file)`. Override this `virtual` method in `Product1` to set `b` from the file.

It might be a bit overkill, but you could consider using the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and set `b` in the `ConcreteVisitor::visit(Product1& product)` method.

As a last resort you could add a `virtual void Product::setB(int b)` that is a no-op for most `Product`s and only actually does anything for `Product1` but it's not a good idea generally and is a good way of making a mess of `Product`.

Remember that the point of a Factory is that the client code shouldn't need to know what `Product` it is working with so if it needs to know it has a `Product1` to set `b` then there is not much point using a Factory.